# Strong pseudoprime base b

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, pseudoprimes

Show that the composite number 1281 is a strong pseudoprime base 41.

"$n-1=2^rm$, then n is a strong pseudoprime base b if either $b^m=1modn$ or $b^{2^sm}=-1modn$"

Ok so I have $n=1281$ and $b=41$

then $n-1=1281-1=1280=2^8*5$ so $r=8$ and $m=5$

then $b^mmodn=41^5mod1281=1280$

and $b^{2^sm}modn=41^{2*5}mod1281=1$

Where am i making a mistake? Is it just a computational error or am I misunderstanding somehting? Do I need to try more "s" values?

Comment: Your definition of a strong pseudoprime seems quite off. In general, to be a probable prime, it should pass a test that all prime numbers pass. Your requirement as stated does not satisfy this (although it is close, if you replace $m$ with $n-1$ and $2^sm$ with $2^{r-1}m$ in the exponents and replace $-1$ with $\pm 1$ after the "or"). Moreover, one typically says a "strong" probable prime if it passes two tests - and you only give one.

Comment: @RghtHndSd oh...well I just got that definition from my textbook.  "replace $2^sm$ with $2^{r−1}m$ in the exponents and replace −1 with ±1 so $41^{2^7*5}mod1281=1$ works?

Comment: Yes, and note this implies that $41^{1280} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod } 1281)$.

Comment: So the correct statement should be: $b^{n-1} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod } n)$ **and** $b^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv \pm 1 (\text{mod } n)$. But you still say your textbook differs? What book?

Comment: I have never heard that a number is called strong-probable prime only after passing two tests. The correct definition of a strong-probable prime to base $a$ : $n=2^t\times m+1$ , $m$ odd, is a strong probable prime to base $a$, if either $a^m\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$ or there is a number $s$ with $0 \le s<t$ with $\large a^{2^s\times m}\equiv -1\ (\ mod\ n)$. $a^m\equiv -1\ (\ mod\ n)$ (the case in the example) is allowed.